# How to make run external shell command in non-blocking mode in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.0

I should change to specific folder so that the output of the script can be exported into a file in that folder (`123.txt` in the example code below).

but this command, which I run from inside my `ruby` code

```
./iw2_broadcast.py
```

takes 5 minutes or more to complete. I try to append `&` to make it run in the background, but it seems it does not work.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
  Dir.chdir(@iw2_dir)
  ` ./iw2_broadcast.py -f 123.txt & `
  puts "123"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a shell script with the execution command

```
# py.sh
./iw2_broadcast.py
```

Execute the above shell script from ruby using `system` command

```
# ruby_script.rb
system("./py.sh")
```

Now your ruby code will be executed without waiting for the output

Answer (score 1):

Adding `&` works with `system()`. You can easily test it with:

```
system("sleep 1 &")
```

So for this precise example:

```
system("./iw2_broadcast.py -f 123.txt &")
```